# Upload photo from Android device to Django backend and save it to database

Tags: android, python, django, easy-thumbnails

I have to upload an image from Android device to a web app written in Python and Django. For storing images, I have made use of **easy thumbnails**.

What I have done so far is convert the image to base64 string to and post it to server. Well this is working perfectly, also if I write the base64 string to png image file it goes smoothly.

Now, I want to save it to the database as far as I know, easy thumbnails save the actual file to some location on server within the app file structure, and saves a link to same in database.

I am not understanding, how do I save the base64 string I receive in POST to my database.

My Model:

```
class Register(models.Model): 
   image = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to=filename, blank=True, null=True, max_length=2048)

def filename(inst, fname):
   f = sha256(fname + str(datetime.now())).hexdigest()
   return '/'.join([inst.__class__.__name__, f])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not stored in the db. It is stored to disk. Only a reference to the file is stored in the db.

```
def Article(models.model):
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

Somewhere you create a new object:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

obj = Article()
data = base64.b64decode(encoded)
# You might want to sanitise `data` here...
# Maybe check if PIL can read the `data`?
obj.image.save('some_file_name.ext', ContentFile(data))
obj.save()
```

Comment: I understand that file is stored on filesystem and only a link is stored in DB. Your solution worked flawlessly. Doing it as a part of web app is simple, with forms. Being an Android thing, I couldn't understand how to do. Thanks a ton.